# SSAS creating cubes dynamically from XMLA

Tags: ssas, xmla

Is it possible to create cubes from XMLA just by replacing the the database and table names?

What I mean is that when you generate from one cube the script to create it, just replace all the related references to tables and database and change the datasource connection string. Now all the tables exist in the other database, I should be able to create a similar cube like this, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can do that but you should be careful not to break it. The XMLA for creating a cube is a whole description of the cube including calculated members, datasource, tables etc. If you want to change just the datasource connection string it is easy. Just one row in the XMLA file and it will work properly.

To change table names etc is very error prone - no matter if you do it by hand or using some regex. If you don't want to redesign the cube and the datasource in visual studio you can try with modifying the XMLA just be careful. Also keep in mind that in that XMLA (generated for example with Script database as create statement) you might also have users/roles/active directory IDs  and stuff like that and if you move to another environment some of these might need to change also.

In the end when you try to process you will see if everything worked fine ;)